# Alter XML while preserving layout

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

What would you use to alter an XML-file while preserving as much as possible of layout, including indentation and comments?

My problem is that I have a couple of massive hand-edited XML-files describing a user interface, and now I need to translate several attributes to another language.

I've tried doing this using Python + ElementTree, but it did not preserve neither whitespace nor comments.

I've seen XSLT being suggested for similar questions, but I don't think that is an alternative in this case, since I need to do some logic and lookups for each attribute.

It would be preferable if attribute order in each element is preserved as well, but I can tolerate changed order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any DOM manipulation module should suite your needs. Layout is just a text data, so it's represented as text nodes in DOM:

```
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
>>> dom = parseString('''\
... <message>
...   <text>
...     Hello!
...   </text>
... </message>''')
>>> dom.childNodes[0].childNodes
[<DOM Text node "u'\n  '">, <DOM Element: text at 0xb765782c>, <DOM Text node "u'\n'">]
>>> text = dom.getElementsByTagName('text')[0].childNodes[0]
>>> text.data = text.data.replace(u'Hello', u'Hello world')
>>> print dom.toxml()
<?xml version="1.0" ?><message>
  <text>
    Hello world!
  </text>
</message>
```

Comment: IMO minidom is not suitable for the task of preserving hand-written XML layout, because it reorders attributes [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662624/preserve-order-of-attributes-when-modifying-with-minidom).

Answer (score 1):

If you use an XSLT processor such as [xt](http://www.blnz.com/xt/index.html), then you can write extension methods in Java that can perform any arbitrary transformation you need.

Having said that, I have used Python's [xml.dom.minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) module successfully for this sort of transformation. It does preserve whitespace and layout.

Comment: As of python 3.9 minidom does not preserve whitespace and layout in my experience. Did this work in former versions?