# python minidom mixing element attributes

Tags: python, xml, minidom

Element is created:

```
        ele = doc.createElement("ele")   
        ele.attributes['var']= 'yes'
        ele.attributes['ret']= 'no'

        main.appendChild(ele)
```

But result has mixed attributes (alphabetic probably):

```
<function ret="no" var="yes"/>
```

Is there any way how to preserve the creating order of attributes in minidom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The attributes are stored in a dictionary, and the order is not preserved. It shouldn't matter much anyway because the order of the attributes in XML has no semantic meaning.

You can use [pxdom](http://www.doxdesk.com/software/py/pxdom.html) instead if you require the attributes in order for some reason.

**Related**

- [Preserve order of attributes when modifying with minidom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662624/preserve-order-of-attributes-when-modifying-with-minidom)