# Python lxml with minidom change element attributes order

Tags: python, attributes, lxml, minidom

I've got problem with minidom. My code is:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

xml_string = ET.tostring(self.model)

reparsed = minidom.parseString(xml_string)        
text = reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="   ")
```

I'm expecting (and when I try to print **xml_string** ,there is right argument order)

```
<def id="A" set="normal"/>
```

but minidom does changes to:

```
<def set="normal" id="A"/>
```

This is lxml tree code

```
temp = ET.SubElement(self.model,"def")
temp.set("id", A)
temp.set("set", "normal")
```

Comment: Related : [Preserve order of attributes when modifying with minidom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662624/preserve-order-of-attributes-when-modifying-with-minidom)

Comment: But i need minidom for indent spaces