# Save XML in custom order of attribute in Python

Tags: python, xml, sorting, encoding

I am trying to get specific order of XML attribute.

Given

```
<OKV s="*****" r="*****" a="*****" g="****" m="*****" e="****" d="****" i="****" n="****" v="1"/>
```

Required :

```
<OKV v="1" n="****" i="****" d="****" e="****" m="*****" g="****"  a="*****" r="*****" s="*****"/>
```

I am trying to implement in Python.

So far when I am using xml library.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('adhar.xml')
```

But it keeps read in that format, 
Please tell how to change the order.
As I am reading correctly in internet explorer when opened the file, But getting reversed order while reading the file or see it in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific xml string you could use [xmltodict](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/) (install with `pip install xmltodict`). This converts the xml data to a python dictionary. Using the following would reverse the order of the `OKV` entry:

```
import xmltodict
import collections
xml_data = '<OKV s="*****" r="*****" a="*****" g="****" m="*****" e="****" d="****" i="****" n="****" v="1"/>'
xml_data_parsed = xmltodict.parse(xml_data)
xml_data_parsed["OKV"] = collections.OrderedDict(reversed(list(xml_data_parsed["OKV"].items())))
xml_data = xmltodict.unparse(xml_data_parsed)
```

If the the part you want to reorder is embedded in a larger xml document you would have to select the deeper nested key to get to e.g. `OKV`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [lxml](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-parse-function) to parse the xml file. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741480/can-elementtree-be-told-to-preserve-the-order-of-attributes/34560411#34560411), it might help get the attributes in the appropriate order.