# python xml write with using namespace

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

Are those two roots the same??

Output xml got changed about the order in the root.

If they are different each other, how could I fix it??

```
#Python 3.7
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ET.register_namespace('xsi', "http://www.w3.org/2001/test")
ET.register_namespace('', "http://www.test.com/test/test/test")
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')

tree.write("test1.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

```
#input XML root
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/test" schemaVersion="2.8" xmlns="http://www.test.com/test/test/test" labelVersion="1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/test/test/test ..\Schema\CLIFSchema.xsd" name="test.xml">
```

```
#output XML root
<root xmlns="http://www.test.com/test/test/test" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/test" labelVersion="1" name="test.xml" schemaVersion="2.8" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/test/test/test ..\Schema\CLIFSchema.xsd">
```

Comment: Yes, those root elements are "the same". The order of attributes and namespace declarations should not matter.

Comment: That's a relief... then can I ask why the order got changed??

Comment: The order is not significant. You should not care about it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51234813/407651

Comment: You might want to test with Python 3.8 or later. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60176826/407651