# Creating XML file with a specific order or attributes using Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree, minidom

I am trying to create a xml file using lxml, I am well aware that the order of attributes in xml doesn't matter but still I am searching for a method to prevent the attributes in a specific order.

I also tried minidom and that didn't workout too.

In lxml I have the following code:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
from collections import OrderedDict
root = ET.Element("Root", OrderedDict([("id","0"),("start","0"),("end","200")]))
ET.tostring(root)
```

This part gives the following ouput with the attributes in the order I wanted since I used OrderedDict here:

```
<Root id="0" start="0" end="200"/>
```

Then I created a Child using the same method:

```
child1 = ET.Element("sentence", OrderedDict([("id","0"),("start","0"),("end","255")]))
root.append(child1)
xml_str = ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
print(xml_str)
```

Printing the xml_str gives output as I expect:

```
<Root id="0" start="0" end="200">\n  <sentence id="0" start="0" end="255"/>\n</Root>
```

But when it comes to writing it down to a xml file:

```
with open('op.xml', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(xml_str)
```

The ouput isn't same when written to op.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Root end="200" start="0" id="0">
       <sentence end="255" start="0" id="0"/>
</Root>
```

Clearly seen that the attributes order have changed, is there any way I can get the ouput as I expect i.e attribute orders being maintained.

I have tried using minidom too, but there also it didn't work even after referring to:
[Preserve order of attributes when modifying with minidom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662624/preserve-order-of-attributes-when-modifying-with-minidom)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library, which is good at extracting data, not very good at modifying XML files, but also can basically meet your needs.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
doc = SimplifiedDoc("<Root></Root>")
doc.Root.setAttrs({"id":"0","start":"0","end":"200"})
doc.Root.setContent("<sentence />")
doc.sentence.setAttrs({"id":"0","start":"0","end":"200"})
utils.saveFile("op.xml",doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<Root id="0" start="0" end="200"><sentence id="0" start="0" end="200" /></Root>
```

Comment: Tried it, this also gives the xml with order of attributes changed, basically not providing the expected result.......
`<Root end="200" start="0" id="0">
      <sentence end="200" start="0" id="0"/>
</Root>`

Comment: @VipulkumarYadav Please confirm. It spelled the attributes in the order in which they were entered into the dictionary.

Comment: What worked for my previous code in the question is this:
I wrote the output to a txt file, and in the txt file the order remained as I wanted, then I changed the extension of the txt file to xml, however this solution only worked for Ubuntu, not working in windows

Comment: It's so strange. I have no problem testing on mac or windows.

Answer (score 0):

Using lxml.etree makes it work:

```
import lxml.etree
from collections import OrderedDict

root = lxml.etree.Element("Root", OrderedDict([("id","0"),("start","0"),("end","200")]))
isVal = lxml.etree.SubElement(root, 'sentence', OrderedDict([("id","0"),("start","0"),("end","255")]))

with open("xyz2.xml", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(lxml.etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8"))

print(open("xyz2.xml", 'r').read())
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Root id="0" start="0" end="200"><sentence id="0" start="0" end="255"/></Root>
```

Comment: It does not look like `OrderedDict` is necessary. For me it works with a regular `dict`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/17654556/407651.

Comment: @mzjn: Yes, makes sense since Python >= 3.7 preserves order

Comment: ElementTree in Python >= 3.8 preserves order. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60176826/407651

Comment: Yes in Python>=3.8 element tree preserves the order - checked....... however this doesnt even work while generating the xml in windows, maybe some problem with windows or some changes in my system? specifically....

Comment: Whats your Python version ?

Comment: Using Python3.6

Comment: Works for me in Python 3.6.8, lxml version 4.5.1 on Mac.